# Как отменить fetch?

Tags: javascript

на форме фильтр + грид

данные с бэка забираю через fetch

полученными данными обновляется грид

запрос довольно тяжелый / долгий

проблема возникает когда пользователь генерит новый запрос до завершения предыдущего

контент в гриде обновляется несколько раз

можно как то прервать / отказаться от "устаревшего" запроса?

P.S.
обертывание fetch в clearTimeout / setTimeout в данной ситуации не спасает

P.S.S.
или както проверять является ли полученный данные результатом последнего promis'а?

`UPDATE`

страница на `ReactJS`

публикация кода ничего не даст, т.к. проблема общего плана

ситуация в том, что нет кнопки "НАЙТИ", запрос генерится при каждом "чихе" в фильтре

фильтр огромный из 10ков полей и выпадающих списков

дисейблить его при каждом запросе не получится по идеалогическим соображениям клиента

вижу единственный вариант это отказываться или игнорировать устаревшие запросы

но хотел поискать `BEST PRACTICES`

`UPDATE2`

```
class View extends Component {

    ...

    updateItems(data) {
        self.state.timeoutItems && clearTimeout(self.state.timeoutItems);
        self.state.timeoutItems = setTimeout(() => {
            self.props.onGetItems(self.calcParams());
        }, config.timeoutItems );
    }  
}


export default connect(
    state => ({
        items: state.items
    }),
    dispatch => ({
        onGetItems: (o) => {
            dispatch(getItems(o));
        }
    })
)(View);
```

...

```
export const getItems = (o = {}) => dispatch => {

    ...

    fetch(url, {  
        method: 'GET',              
        headers: {
            "Content-type": "application/json",
            "Accept": "application/json"
        },  
    })
    .then( (response) => response.json() )
    .then((data) => {

        ==>> (1) <<==

        dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_ITEMS_SUCCESS', data: data });
    })  
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log('Request failed', error);  
    });
}
```

можно ли в точке (1) определить к какому promise относится полученный результат?

Comment: Осмелюсь предположить, что имеет место использование некоего фреймворка, не так ли?

Comment: зачем нет кода примера?

Comment: Есть как я делал, не знаю будет возможно лишним, но можете попробовать rxjs, и там есть то что вам нужно вроде бы оператор debounce() и в параметре количество милисекунд, в течении которых нельзя делать запрос после запроса.

Comment: https://youtu.be/3szEGhrFrts?t=1h22m30s

Comment: Для ответа на вопрос «Как отменить fetch?» пример вроде бы не нужен) А я где-то читал, что отменить его нельзя( Но проверять актуальность данных с помощью собственного кода точно можно

Comment: тоже видел информацию что в отличие от XMLHttpRequest у fetch нет метода abort

Comment: обновил вопрос, добавил код

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31061838/2076787

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На текущее время нативно отменить `fetch` нельзя, это потому что он использует механизм `Promise`-ов, в которых тоже нет механизма прерывания. Поэтому приходится ухитряться и писать костыли

Есть [библиотека axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios), тоже использует `Promise`, правда работает вроде все еще на стандартном `XMLHttpRequest`, но возможность [отмены там есть](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios#cancellation):

```
var CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
var source = CancelToken.source();

axios.get('/user/12345', {
  cancelToken: source.token
}).catch(function(thrown) {
  if (axios.isCancel(thrown)) {
    console.log('Request canceled', thrown.message);
  } else {
    // handle error
  }
});

// cancel the request (the message parameter is optional)
source.cancel('Operation canceled by the user.');
```

Если хотите использовать нативный `fetch` придется пока писать свою реализацию отмены запроса (да и то, это не будет настоящей отменой запроса, потому что ответ все равно придет, просто вы его проигнорируете)

**UPD**

[Дискасс на эту тему](https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/447)

Comment: вот вопрос, как определить что данные относятся к `устаревшему` запросу?

Comment: @ravend, создавать ссылку на текущий запрос, если мы пытаемся отправить новый, то текущий абортим/удаляем/что-нибудь делаем, и обновляем ссылку

Comment: @ThisMan плз, зайди в общий чят

Comment: @nörbörnën куда?

Comment: я тут спрошу: "на ru.so есть вопрос ru.stackoverflow.com/q/680034, который ассоциирован с вопросом en.so stackoverflow.com/q/31061838. на en.so сообщество поддерживает "ответ на вопрос" в актуальном состоянии,  принятый ответ был отредактирован ещё год назад, теперь в нём появилось описание механизма остановки fetch-запроса с помощью AbortSignal.
как поступить с вопросом ru.so - отредактировать существующий ответ или написать новый? @ThisMan, как ты отнесёшься к тому, что я вечерком отредактирую твой ответ?"

Comment: @nörbörnën я не против, давай отредактируем существующий

Comment: @ThisMan, хорошо

Answer (score 0):

Способа отменить `fetch` [нет](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31061838/6275986) и вроде как [не предвидится](https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/447).

Выбрать наиболее новый и отрисовать именно его можно как-то так:

```js
let counter = 0; // Флаг итератора количества запросов

function buildRequest(){
  console.info(`Запрос #${counter + 1} послан`);
  makeRequest(++counter); // Новый запрос получает более большое число
}

function makeRequest(num){
  setTimeout(_ => {
    if(counter > num){ // Если итератор больше текущего числа, значит был запрос позже, выходим
      console.info(`Запрос #${num} отменён, есть запросы позже`);
      return;
    }
    
    // Иначе рисуем ответ
    console.info(`Запрос #${num} начинает отрисовку`);
  }, 1000);
}

buildRequest();
setTimeout(_ => buildRequest(), 500);
setTimeout(_ => buildRequest(), 1000);
```

Но сервер всё равно будет в поте процессора трудится.

Иначе либо ставьте запросы в очередь, либо сделайте заблокируйте фильтры на момент запроса.